# Python recognize part of string (position and length)

Tags: python, string

I have got a file (.VAR) which gives me a positions and lengths in a strings per row, see the example below.

> *STRING1 **1L8**:StringONE
> *STRINGWITHVARIABLELENGTH2 *ABC **29L4**:StringTWO
> *STRINGWITHLENGTH3 *ABC **33L2**:StringTHREE

How do i retrieve the **" xxLxxx:"** value, which is always preceded by a space and always ends with a colon, but never on the same location within the string.

Preferably I would like to find the number before L as the position, and the number behind L as the length, but only searching for "L" would give me also the input from other values within the string. Therefore I think I have to use the space_number_L_number_colon to recognize this part, but I don't know how.

Any thoughts? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex here.

Example:

```
s='''*STRING1 1L8:StringONE
*STRINGWITHVARIABLELENGTH2 *ABC 29L4:StringTWO
*STRINGWITHLENGTH3 *ABC 33L2:StringTHREE'''

import re
out = re.findall(r'\s(\d+)L(\d+):', s)
```

output: `[('1', '8'), ('29', '4'), ('33', '2')]`

As integers:

```
out = [tuple(map(int, x)) for x in re.findall(r'\s(\d+)L(\d+):', s)]
```

output: `[(1, 8), (29, 4), (33, 2)]`

##### regex:

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C0dXfM/1)

```
\s      # space
(\d+)   # capture one or more digits
L       # literal L
(\d+)   # capture one or more digits
:       # literal :
```